# Can I set different scroll duration per item in caroufredsel?

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

How to get my carousel scroll different items at different duration? I have tried playing with this event to no avail.

```
$('#carousel').triggerHandler('configuration')
```

e.g. Show slide 1 for 5 second, slide 2 for 10 seconds and so on.

```
    jQuery(".desktop-carouselContainer").carouFredSel({
        scroll: {
            fx: "crossfade",
            onAfter: function (data) {
                data.scroll.duration = jQuery("#promo-timer", this).html() * 1000;
            }
        },
        auto: {
            progress: {
                bar: ".timer",
                updater: function (percentage) {
                    jQuery(this).width(percentage / (jQuery("#promos-container .desktop-carouselContainer li a img").width() / (jQuery(".pagination").width() + 15)) + "%");
                    jQuery(this).css({ "left": jQuery("#promos-container .desktop-carouselContainer li a img").width() - jQuery(".pagination").width() - 15 });
                },
                interval: 30
            }
        },
        pagination: {
            container: ".pagination",
            anchorBuilder: function (nr) {
                var src = jQuery(".promo-title", this).html();
                return '<div class="pagination-link">' + src + '</div>';
            }
        },
        width: 945,
        height: 429
    })
```

> Edit: (Solution)

After playing with it for a while, heres how I got it working:

```
    ...
    auto: {
            onAfter: function (data) {
                jQuery('.desktop-arouselContainer').triggerHandler('configuration').auto.timeoutDuration = jQuery("#promo-timer", this).html() * 1000;
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the same ID's contents for every slide. Seeing that an ID must be unique, how were you hoping that would work?

Comment: #promo-timer control is inside a repeater control. So for some reason  jQuery("#promo-timer", this).html() does return the right value for each slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I got it working:

```
    ...
    auto: {
            onAfter: function (data) {
                jQuery('.desktop-arouselContainer').triggerHandler('configuration').auto.timeoutDuration = jQuery("#promo-timer", this).html() * 1000;
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: whats your email id i have new question but also have big code need your help ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to use an event callback to modify the options after each cycle. Something like:

```
 // WARNING: HASTILY-WRITTEN AND UNTESTED PSEUDO-CODE!
// 
$("#carousel").carouFredSel({
    ... ,
    scroll: {
        onAfter: function(data) {
            // set duration depending on slide index
            case ( ... slide index = 1 ... ) {
                myDuration = 2000;
            }

            this.duration = myDuration;
        }
    },
    ...             
});
```

Comment: In theory this should have worked, but it didn't. :( Is there anything I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for a way to make multiple sliders at one page use different timeoutDuration:

max,min - your maximum and minimum time intervals

```
...
    auto: {
            onAfter: function (data) {
                        $(this).triggerHandler('configuration').auto.timeoutDuration = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
                    }
        }
    ...
```